# Java Arraylist Data extraction

Tags: java, json, arraylist

How would you extract the data as follows:

I want to extract from this arraylist:

```
[{itemname=Original, number=12}, {itemname=BBQ, number=23}, {itemname=CatchUp, number=23}]
```

This array:

```
{"Original":12,"BBQ":23,"CatchUp":23}
```

Thanks in advance! Here's the code used to generate the hashmap:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
for (int i = 0; i<7;i++) {
 HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
  map.put("itemname",chips[i]);
  map.put("number",chipentry[i]);
  list.add(map);
 }
```

Comment: Can you post any code to explain how you create the `ArrayList`?

Comment: What **exactly** is the content of the list and what **exactly** should be the content of the array? In terms of Java objects, please!

Comment: Your "array" appears to have compound elements which you've specified using colons. What exactly do you mean? What type would your array use? Or are you *really* talking about a map?

Comment: Sorry folks, yeah - it's an arraylist of hashmaps, and I want to convert it to JSON as c0mrade deduced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want to convert it to Json, using google gson http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ its very easy

"Provide simple toJson() and fromJson() methods to convert Java objects to JSON and vice-versa"

Here is what I mean :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(map); //where map is your map object
```

Comment: Thank you c0mrade. I ended up creating a new JSONObject instead because this didn't get the quite exact format I wanted, but it helped me figure it out. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip - I have changed to the following code:

```
  ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  for (int i = 0; i<7;i++) {
     HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
     map.put("itemname",chips[i]);
     map.put("number",chipentry[i]);
     list.add(map);
     System.out.println(gson.toJson(map));
  }
```

And the result is https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1qg4.png

I imported com.google.gson.Gson, is there something else I'm missing? Please excuse my newbness and thanks for the help!

Comment: I've edited your answer, this will print each map converted to json in your arraylist

Comment: from this it looks like it's generating 7 JSON object instead of one single - is there a way to combine the JSON objects together and store in a variable?

Comment: yes, convert the whole list to json instead, `gson.toJson(list);`

Comment: @c0mrade: thanks, now one last thing - instead of getting the desired format of [{"Original":12,"BBQ":23,"CatchUp":23}] I obtain this: [{"itemname":"Original","number","12"},{"itemname":"BBQ","number":"23"},{"itemname":"CatchUp","number":"23"}]. What do I need to change in my code to get the desired format?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the data as you expected, you can use **Jackson JSON processor**. It allows you to read and write JSON easily. You can follow their tutorial [here](http://jackson.codehaus.org/Tutorial).

Fist you have to download the relevant jar files(2 files) provided by them.

So the following code snippet should solve your problem, and the result is written to the `jsonResult.json` file.

```
    String[] chips = {"Original", "BBQ", "CatchUp"};
    String[] chipentry = {"12", "23", "23"};

    List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("itemname", chips[i]);
        map.put("number", chipentry[i]);
        list.add(map);
    }

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> untyped = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    untyped.put("result", list);
    mapper.writeValue(new File("jsonResult.json"), untyped);
```

And following is the output of the file,

```
{"result":[{"itemname":"Original","number":"12"},{"itemname":"BBQ","number":"23"},{"itemname":"CatchUp","number":"23"}]}
```

Comment: Thank you Chathuranga, it's not quite what I was looking for but it helped me out. I can only accept one answer but again, much appreciated.

Comment: :) its ok staeit... anyway if you figure it out thats great.... if you are willing, you can share your final result as well... it can help others who faced the same issue... cheers!