# How can I create this JsonObject using Gson API?

Tags: java, json, api, serialization, gson

I've been having trouble getting this json object to serialize/deserialize properly:

> ```
> {
>   series:[{
>       data:[[long,int], ... ],
>       label:String
>   },
>   ...
>   ],
>   options:{
>       mouse:{track:true},
>       xaxis:{noTicks:10},
>       points:{show:true},
>       lines:{show:true}
>   }
> }
> ```

Here is what I tried; however, Gson doesn't seem to like doing fromJson, although, it does correctly do toJson.

```
class JsonBlock {
    ArrayList<Series> series = new ArrayList();
    String options = "mouse:{track:true},"
                   + "xaxis:{noTicks:10},"
                   + "points:{show:true},"
                   + "lines:{show:true}";
    public String toString() { return String.format("series:%s,options:%s",series, options); }
}

class Series {
    ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList();
    String label = "";
    public Series(String label, Data d) { this.label = label; data.add(d); }
    public String toString() { return String.format("data:%s,label:%s", data, label); }
}

class Data {
    long date = -1;
    int qty = 0;
    public Data(long date, int qty) { this.date = date; this.qty = qty; }
    public String toString() { return date + "," + qty; }
}
```

Any hints or answers are appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty straight forward, take a look at this :

[Java Arraylist Data extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592575/java-arraylist-data-extraction/5592633#5592633)

Comment: I've tried a lot of the suggestions on that page, but none of them are helping me fix the error of deserializing. It properly serializes (toJson); however, it has trouble taking that serialized string and deserializing it.

Comment: The issue was with deserializing the List<Series>. Anyways, Gson 1.7 just fixed the entire error, haha! woot