# Howto cut this string and put into an array?

Tags: java, regex, json

lets say I have a String like this

```
[{ "name" : "Ronald" , "firstname" : "Ruck"} , { "name" : "Yunchin" , "firstname" : "Cha"} , { "name" : "Klaus" , "firstname" : "Mixer"}]
```

Sometimes the string is shorter/longer, important is that at start there is [{ and at the end }]. I would like to read just the name and firstname, put a name + firstname to one String and then put every single Name+Firstname-String in an array. Ok sounds weird? If I would iterate my new array with these names there should be an output: Ronald Ruck, Yunchin Cha, Klaus Mixer... Any ideas? I know something with regex but im not good at it. Thank you!

**Edit:**
Yes it looks like a Json. But if Im using a json reader like http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ I get an error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject` At first I tought its  because there is an "[" at the start and a "]" at the end. Without that I get: `Unexpected token COMMA(,) at position 44.` So its maybe not a real json? I could try http://jackson.codehaus.org/ too, but im not sure that will work.

**Edit2:**
Ok everything is fine :) With json-simple its working, just have to use the JSONArray correctly. The solution with the Gson Lib is ok too, thank you all.

Comment: Looks like JSON. Get a JSON parser to do it for you! http://json.org/java/

Comment: yeah, like Jackson  http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Comment: @OverStack I can almost guarantee it will be easier than trying to do it with a regular expression.

Comment: Definitely use an existing JSON solution; this is a wheel not worth re-inventing.

Comment: If your string has a variable number of "persons", than you can't do this with a regex. Or at least not with Java's regex flavor...

Comment: I assume you did something wrong when trying to parse the string with JSON simple. Could you post the relevant code portion? Note that `JSONArray` doesn't extend `JSONObject` and thus you'll have to decide which one to use. The parser returns a `JSONArray` since you have an array as the top level element. I assume you're trying to assign that to a variable of type `JSONObject` which won't work.

Comment: It really should work with a json parser (and that is the way to go here). But if you do want to code something yourself use the split method of String, eg: String[] nameAndFirstName ="yourString".split("}, {"); Then iterate over that array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Arraylist Data extraction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592575/java-arraylist-data-extraction)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string you provided is a valid json string. You can check the validity [here](http://jsonlint.com/). You can use [Gson library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse json string in java.

Read this [Tutorial](http://rishabhsays.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/parsing-list-of-json-objects-with-gson/) first than my code will make more sense to you.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

String json1 = "[{\"Name\":\"Ronald\",\"Firstname\":\"Reagan\"},{\"Name\":\"Chris\",\"Firstname\":\"Jeoff\"}]";
JsonElement json = new JsonParser().parse(json1);
JsonArray array= json.getAsJsonArray();    
Iterator iterator = array.iterator();    
while(iterator.hasNext()){

JsonElement json2 = (JsonElement)iterator.next();
     
Gson gson = new Gson();
GetResult gresult = gson.fromJson(json2, GetResult.class);
System.out.println("Name:" + gresult.getName());
System.out.println("FirstName:" + gresult.getFirstname());
```

Now, the corresponding `Getter and Setter class` for the above code:

```
 public String Name;
 public String Firstname; //Note the variable names are same as the name in Json String.

 public String getFirstname() {
 return Firstname;
 }
 public String getName() {
 return Name;
 }
```

Output =

> Name:Ronald
>
> FirstName:Reagan
>
> Name:Chris
>
> FirstName:Jeoff

Comment: Hej thats a good one. I figured out with json-simple its working too (ok you have to change here and there some stuff in the code ^^ but its the same). Thank you.

Comment: @OverStack it sounds like you didn't use this answer yourself. If you found an alternate solution, please post this yourself and accept that as the answer.